# INSERT query works in SQL but doesn't work from android app

Tags: java, php, android, database

I'm trying to send an INSERT query to my SQL DataBase but it doesn't work and no error is appearing but the query works if I send it from phpMyAdmin.
here is my PHP code :

```
if ($_POST['func'] == 2) {
$dbca = taskdb();
$dbca->set_charset("utf8");
$mobileUser = $_POST['phone'];
$fullnameUser = $_POST['fullname'];
$usernameUser = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (UserPhone, Username, UserFullname) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$result = $dbca->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param("sss", $mobileUser,$fullnameUser,$usernameUser);
echo json_encode(array('profileUser' => 'DONE'));
}
```

and here is my java(client) code which is inside an AsyncT doInBacground:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.26/MyProject/fetchData.php");
  try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("func", "2"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", Login.user_phone));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullname", fullname.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.getText().toString()));
    Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());
    UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
    form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(form);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    Signup.InputStreamToStringExample str = new Signup.InputStreamToStringExample();
    responseSignup = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
    Log.e("response", "response -----" + responseSignup);
    jsonresponse = new JSONObject(responseSignup);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
```

I'm getting "DONE" as the response in client but no row would be inserted into my DataBase.
any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
$result->execute();
```

after

```
$result->bind_param("sss",  $mobileUser,$fullnameUser,$usernameUser);
```

in php file

Comment: Thanks a lot :) sorry for this question , I'm just new in PHP